# Unity android app crash on launch, need guide on the crash log

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

I would like to start my app without any problem. Currently, when I press on my app, it instantly popout 'Unfortunately, MyGame has stopped' without even going into the app. PS: I'm using Android Studio Virtual Machine with Android 4.2 armeabi-v7a.

These are the crash log.

>

```
 02-11 11:38:56.709: D/AudioHardware(92): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby. 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: D/AudioHardware(92): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open(0x0003f000) 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period sz multiplier 16 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period cnt 6 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period_cnt 6 period_sz 1024 channels 2 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: I/alsa_mix(92): -->Playback Path access 3 
    02-11 11:38:56.709: I/ActivityManager(339): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=            [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000         cmp=com.MyCompany.MyGames/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from pid 555 
    02-11 11:38:56.769: I/ActivityManager(339): Start proc com.MyCompany.MyGames for activity     com.MyCompany.MyGames/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: pid=5760 uid=10074 gids={50074, 3003,     1028} 
    02-11 11:38:56.809: I/InputReader(339): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004 
    02-11 11:38:56.809: I/InputReader(339): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='gslX680', size 480x272,     orientation 3, mode 1, display id 0 
    02-11 11:38:56.809: I/ActivityManager(339): Config changes=1480 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w544dp h912dp 80dpi lrg long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.29} 
    02-11 11:38:56.829: D/PhoneApp(523): updateProximitySensorMode: state = IDLE 
    02-11 11:38:56.829: D/PhoneApp(523): updateProximitySensorMode: lock already released. 
    02-11 11:38:56.879: I/qtaguid(339): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10074) res=-1 errno=1 
    02-11 11:38:56.879: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(339): setKernelCountSet(10074, 1) failed with     errno -1 
    02-11 11:38:56.919: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5342K, 61% free 4313K/10804K, paused     11ms+7ms, total 81ms 
    02-11 11:38:56.929: D/dalvikvm(415): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms 
    02-11 11:38:56.939: D/dalvikvm(5760): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.MyCompany.MyGames-    1/lib/libmain.so 0x40eceeb8 
    02-11 11:38:56.939: D/dalvikvm(5760): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.MyCompany.MyGames-    1/lib/libmain.so 0x40eceeb8 
    02-11 11:38:56.989: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_EXPLICIT freed 349K, 64% free 3963K/10804K, paused 8ms+5ms, total 61ms 
    02-11 11:38:57.079: D/WallpaperManager(415): LOAD DEFAULT WALLPAPER  ......false 
    02-11 11:38:57.109: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 64% free 3972K/10804K, paused 32ms,     total 32ms 
    02-11 11:38:57.119: I/dalvikvm-heap(415): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.949MB for 4096016-byte     allocation 
    02-11 11:38:57.149: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 27% free 7972K/10804K, paused 36ms, total 36ms 
    02-11 11:38:57.189: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 27% free 7972K/10804K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 40ms 
    02-11 11:38:57.199: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(555): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection 
    02-11 11:38:57.209: I/ActivityManager(339): Displayed     com.MyCompany.MyGames/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +450ms 
    02-11 11:38:57.209: E/dalvikvm(5760): Could not find class 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup',     referenced from method bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.<init> 
    02-11 11:38:57.209: W/dalvikvm(5760): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 364 (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;) in Lbitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge$a; 
    02-11 11:38:57.209: D/dalvikvm(5760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000b 
    02-11 11:38:57.209: E/dalvikvm(5760): Could not find class 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup', referenced from method bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.a 
    02-11 11:38:57.219: W/dalvikvm(5760): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 364     (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;) in Lbitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge$a; 
    02-11 11:38:57.219: D/dalvikvm(5760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x001b 
    02-11 11:38:57.639: I/Unity(5760): SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 2, Memory = 1024mb 
    02-11 11:38:57.639: I/Unity(5760): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0x3), 0     little (mask: 0x0) 
    02-11 11:38:57.639: I/Unity(5760): ApplicationInfo com.MyCompany.MyGames version 1.0 build af272e66-    7bbb-4def-99e7-ba3273b24496 
    02-11 11:38:57.639: I/Unity(5760): Built from '2019.1/release' branch, Version '2019.1.2f1     (3e18427e571f)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled' 
    02-11 11:38:58.329: D/libEGL(5760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    02-11 11:38:58.329: D/libEGL(5760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so 
    02-11 11:38:58.339: D/libEGL(5760): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so 
    02-11 11:38:58.359: D/Unity(5760):  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot     GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24     GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil     GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync     GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer     GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness 
    02-11 11:38:58.369: W/ContextImpl(5760): Unable to create external cache directory 
    02-11 11:38:59.569: D/dalvikvm(339): GC_EXPLICIT freed 755K, 28% free 7178K/9876K, paused 4ms+11ms,     total 106ms
    02-11 11:39:01.119: W/ContextImpl(5760): Unable to create external files directory 
    01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected: 1 
    01-01 00:00:00.000: E/(-1): Device disconnected
```

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef Thanks for the reminder, I have edited my question.

Comment: It shows java class error. Which JDK version you have used ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya it's JDK installed with Unity ( based on OpenJDK 1.8.0_152.

Comment: Have you used proguard ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Not really sure what proguard is. I do have 'User Proguard File' unchecked, Both 'Release' and 'Debug' under 'Minify' as 'None'.